# Alternative to Row_Number Over Partition

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, reporting

I have data formatted as such:

```
ID          Agent          AgentState          StateType          StartTime          EndTime
            Smith, Bob     WaitingForCall      Productive         08:00              10:00
            Smith, Bob     OnCall              Productive         10:00              10:30
            Smith, Bob     LoggedOut           NonProductive      10:30              10:45
            Smith, Bob     WaitingForCall      Productive         10:45              11:00
            Smith, Bob     OnCall              Productive         11:00              11:45
            Smith, Bob     OnCall              Productive         11:45              12:15
            Smith, Bob     LoggedOut           NonProductive      12:15              13:15
```

What I want to accomplish is combining all the time ranges to just use the productive type. So the end result would be:

```
ID          Agent          StateType          StartTime          EndTime
            Smith, Bob     Productive         08:00              10:30
            Smith, Bob     NonProductive      10:30              10:45
            Smith, Bob     Productive         10:45              12:15
            Smith, Bob     NonProductive      12:15              13:15
```

In a previous job I had access to SQL servers and I could accomplish this by using Row_Number Over Partition. Now that I only have access to excel/access I am finding it difficult to create a way to "squish" the data to just StateType duration. The system where I pull the data can't be changed so the original format can't be modified either.

Comment: Does "Person" represent names? If so, instead of "Person", should use some phony names in example and do you really need names in output?

Comment: I am sorry, yes there will be multiple people in the list with different names.

Comment: Do you have a lot of rows of data? Just wondering if it's worth considering a solution just in Excel or whether it would have to be in Access?

Comment: Good question, the data set that comes out is pretty big with quite a few rows. I can do whatever in either. I already have a macro that formats the raw file a bit (get rid of some junk header rows) so I can add it at that point or after importing to access.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way to go about this, but it should work. You can probably do it somehow in SQL but I'm not sure how to.

This assumes your data is in order, if it isn't you will probably need to define a basic container class to hold the values until the end.

This will require a new table with the relevant columns added.

```
Sub compress()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim employee As String
    Dim state As String
    Dim starting As Date
    Dim ending As Date

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1") 'Use real table name


    Dim appendtable As Recordset
    Set appendtable = db.OpenRecordset("Table2") 'Use real table name
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        employee = ![agent]
        state = ![statetype]
        starting = Format(![starttime], "HH:MM") 'You probably don't need the format
        ending = Format(![endtime], "HH:MM")
        Do Until .EOF
            If employee = ![agent] And state = ![statetype] Then
                ending = Format(![endtime], "HH:MM") 'Track ending times
            Else
                appendtable.AddNew 'Append data
                appendtable![agent] = employee
                appendtable![statetype] = state
                appendtable![starttime] = starting
                appendtable![endtime] = ending
                appendtable.Update

                employee = ![agent] 'Reset Data
                state = ![statetype]
                starting = Format(![starttime], "HH:MM")
                ending = Format(![endtime], "HH:MM")
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: So do I need to create a blank table for table2?

Comment: Ahh yeah, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Table2 would likely be considered a 'temp' table - holds data only for duration of process and data is purged each time. So might want to add a line to delete all records at beginning of procedure. `CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM Table2"`.

Comment: When opening the recordset based on the original table, you probably should use a SQL statement with "ORDER BY Agent, StartTime", as otherwise there is no guarantee what order the data will be in, which makes the rest of the code not work as expected.

Comment: True, though I don't know what they need it for so I didn't add that in. If it's an excel export or something then definitely.

Comment: Just wanted to come back and let you know it worked like a charm.